# How do I make a channel? (discord.js)

Tags: discord.js

I have a problem with creating a channel. Here is my code:

```
let id = message.author.id.toString().substr(0, 4) + message.author.discriminator;
var name = `order-${message.author}-${id}`

message.createChannel(name);
```

This is the error I am getting:

`TypeError: message.createChannel is not a function`

I hope someone could help me! :-)

Answer (score 0):

`message.createChannel()` is not a thing. You need to use [`guild.channels.create()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannelManager?scrollTo=create).

For a full list of permissions, [click here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Permissions?scrollTo=s-FLAGS).

```js
const category = message.guild.channels.cache.get(CATEGORY_ID)
message.guild.channels.create(name, { 
  parent: category,
  permissionOverwrites: [
    {
      id: message.author.id, // Takes either user ID or role ID
      deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL', 'SEND_MESSAGES'], // Denies permission(s)
      allow: ['ATTACH_FILES'] // Allows permission(s)
    },
    {
      id: message.guild.id, // guild.id doubles as the role id for the default role `@everyone`
      deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL']
    }
  ]
})
```

Comment: When I do that I get this error:

```ReferenceError: guild is not defined```

Comment: My bad, I fixed the answer

Comment: NP, how do i add a parent? (setParent(CategoryID))

Comment: Edited my answer, that should help you set a parent, replace `CATEGORY_ID` with the ID of the category

Comment: Thx bro! You help me a lot with this

Comment: But it doesn't work, I don't get an error either. This is my code now:

`var name = order-${message.member.user.username}
    const category = message.guild.channels.cache.get(708800011160256582);

    message.guild.channels.create(name, { parent: category })

}`

Comment: That's because you passed the category ID as a number, you need to pass it as a string `.get('708800011160256582')`. Side note: you don't need to do `message.member.user.username` just use `message.author.username`

Comment: Thxx! And then probably one of the last questions, how exactly does overwritePermissions work.

Comment: I advise you to create a new question to ask that to make it easier for people looking for answers

Comment: i have to wait 90 minutes

Comment: Do you want to modify permissions when creating the channel or after?

Comment: when creating =)

Comment: Check my edit, added an explanation to `permissionOverwrites`

Comment: Aha thx! And how do I ensure that a specific role can see that channel? And normal players don't

Comment: I added an explanation on how to deny/allow permissions for the `@everyone` role

Comment: guild.id or message.guild.id =)

Comment: message.guild.id, you're right, I corrected my answer

Comment: If an answer solves your question/issue, you need to accept it to let others know the question has been answered and to let others know what worked.